# Kong/Nginx Closes connections despite keep alive

Tags: nginx, kong

Folks
I have an issue where I see these messages continuously in kong's error logs

```
.............................
[info] 9748#0: *61537 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while sending to client, client: 1.2.3.4, server: kong, request: "POST /foo HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://foo.com/fooapi"
..............................
```

I took a TCP dump of what's happenning and analyzed the dump

I can clearly see that Kong server is closing the connection after sending the response(http status code 200, with a FIN,ACK) for which the client responds with an RST,ACK

I have two questions

- Is it valid for the Client (a HAP load balancer, in my case) to send
  an RST without sending a FIN.
- I have enabled Keepalives in the
  nginx.conf (so Kong server should not be closing connections)

  ```
  http {
  keepalive_timeout 60;
  keepalive_requests 10000;
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  include 'nginx-kong.conf';
  }
  ```

What is that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: about haproxy: yes, it's valid to close a connection with RST; doing so, the connection on the nginx side is immediately close, avoiding the TIME_WAIT state.